# Infinite upper and lower CL after fitting the model (glmmtmb)

Tags: lsmeans, glmmtmb

I am new in GLMM. In my dataset, There are 2 islands, 2 sites were selected (nonrandom) per each island, 6 transects randomly were located on each site, then the number of corals was counted in three categories: bleached, partial-bleached and health. The data are collected for 2 years.
[image]
The transect (random effect) is nested within sites, and sites (fixed effect) within island (fixed effect). I ran a generalized linear mixed model as below to overcome overdispersion:

```
modelF8 <- glmmTMB(No.coral ~ (1|transect) + year +island + site + health_status + genus,
                     data = data,
                     family = nbinom1)
```

1. The residual plot seems a bit unacceptable, however the KS test, dispersin and outlier test are not significant. Should I do something or I can rely on the QQplot rsults and go on?

[image]

To test the interactions, I used emmneas as below

```
emmip(modelF8, ~year, type="response")
lsmeans <- emmeans(modelF8, ~ year, cont="pairwise", adjust="none", type="response", alpha=0.05)
lsmeans
$emmeans
 year response   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 2014   0.0787 4.92 8032 2.22e-16 1.29e+52
 2015   0.0847 5.29 8032 2.22e-16 1.39e+52
 2016   0.0898 5.61 8032 2.22e-16 1.48e+52
 2017   0.0523 3.27 8032 2.22e-16 8.60e+51

Results are averaged over the levels of: site, health_status, genus, island 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 

$contrasts
 contrast    ratio     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 2014 / 2015 0.929 0.0673 8032 -1.014  0.3105 
 2014 / 2016 0.876 0.0632 8032 -1.834  0.0667 
 2014 / 2017 1.503 0.1242 8032  4.927  <.0001 
 2015 / 2016 0.943 0.0677 8032 -0.818  0.4135 
 2015 / 2017 1.617 0.1337 8032  5.817  <.0001 
 2016 / 2017 1.715 0.1408 8032  6.572  <.0001
```

The problem is the infinite upper and lower CL that caused weird plotting display of lsmeans too.

[image]

And also Pr(>Chisq) of anova:

```
Anova(modelF8, type = 3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: No.coral
                 Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)    296.900  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
year            48.203  3  1.928e-10 ***
island           0.000  1          1    
site            26.877  3  6.248e-06 ***
health_status  447.973  2  < 2.2e-16 ***
genus         1277.480 20  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

What's wrong and what shall I do? Thanks in advance.

alleffect plots after correctin the model based on Russ Lenth suggestions:

[image]

Comment: For starters, I think sire and island are completely confounded; so take island out of the model because site covers it. Second, are those particular four sites of fixed interest, or are they just four sites used in the experiment? You might consider using the random term (1 | site / transect) and leaving site out of the fixed effects. Otherwise, with the model you have, perhaps the random term should be (1 | site:transect), unless the transect IDs really are distinguishable from one site to the next.

Comment: Modeling issues aside, it appears you have very few 1s and mostly 0s, so it is not surprising that the rates are hard to estimate. This being a mixed model, if the variations among transects are substantial, a lot of within-transect variation cancels out when you take differences, making the comparisons easier to estimate (smaller SE), as you see in the P values for comparisons.

Comment: @Russ Lenth, Many thanks for your detailed reply. I corrected the model considering your suggestions. Rsiduals vs predicted plot did not change significantly, however, the model is better fitted since now I have 'site' and 'health_status' plots in addition to 'year' plot.  sorry but I couldn't figure out what shall I do with the infinite upper and lower CL, that is the remained problem? (I added a snapshot of data and alleffect plot into the main post).

Comment: @Russ Lenth, we selected those specific sites because they are the most important localities for corals.